# fetching only year and month from a date saved in the format of strtotime

Tags: php, date, strtotime

My date string value is `1478025000`. want to get year and month in the string format itself from this string,is it possible? the day should be 0 and next month and next year like that.
my desired output should be `1477852200`

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: anybody have any idea

Comment: What you have tried so far. What is your expected output. Post your attempts? Its pretty Unclear what you want to achieve over here

Comment: please add your desire output in question and what you have tried!

Comment: sorry..my table containing date field and the value stored in that  for date `02-11-2016` is `1478025000` .now am fetching that result back in the format of string itself but i need to get only the value for `11-2016`.

Comment: i had added my desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$epoch = 1478025000;
$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch"); // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
echo $dt->format('Y-m'); // Display as year and month: YYYY-MM
echo $dt->format('m-Y'); // Display as month and year: MM-YYYY
```

If you want to get just the year and month as an epoch, try something like:

```
$epoch = 1478025000;
$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch"); // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
$year = $dt->format('Y');
$day = $dt->format('n');
$answer = new DateTime();
$answer->setDate($year, $month, 0);
$answer->setTime(0, 0, 0);
echo $answer->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: its coming in the date format like `11-2016`.but want to get this in the string only

Comment: you want it like `8025` is it? @MOHAMMED

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us what your expected out should be like? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: now what you have written is correct..but how can i write more simply

Comment: @MOHAMMED did you try the last block of code? I am quite sure that this is correct answer...

Comment: yaa its correct..but i had changed it like this `echo strtotime(date('00-m-Y',1478025000));` for reducing the codes